# Detecting dynamic parameters and return types

Tags: c#, reflection, dynamic-typing

I've looked all over stack overflow but haven't been able to find a solution to this yet. How can I use reflection to distinguish between `dynamic` and `object` parameters and return types?

For example, suppose I have a number of methods in a class like this:

```
public void Foo(dynamic d) { }
public void Bar(object o) { }

public dynamic Foo() { return "foo"; }
public object Bar() { return "bar"; }
```

How can I get only the `Foo`'s and not `Bar`'s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# compiler emits a [`DynamicAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.dynamicattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) on any `dynamic` parameters, return types, or members, which you can detect via [`GetCustomAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kk93tbd(v=vs.110).aspx). For the sake of brevity, you can define a helper method like this:

```
static bool IsDynamic(ParameterInfo pi) {
    return pi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DynamicAttribute), true).Length > 0;
}
```

Or if using .NET 4.5 or later, you can extension methods from the extremely helpful [`CustomAttributeExtensions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.customattributeextensions_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) class:

```
static bool IsDynamic(ParameterInfo pi) {
    return pi.IsDefined(typeof(DynamicAttribute));
}
```

Then you get the just those methods that either select or return a dynamic type like this:

```
dynamicMethods = myType.GetMethods()
    .Where(mi => IsDynamic(mi.ReturnParameter) || mi.GetParameters().Any(IsDynamic));
```

<sup>Note that the C# compiler will throw an error if you try to use the `DynamicAttribute` directly, but other CIL compilers may not.</sup>

Comment: Very nice - I am sad to say that I have a use case for this since I am currently trying to clean up an entire section of our codebase that has `dynamic` strewn throughout it (when it didn't need to be!). This will help me search for it.